How to stop Windows on external hard drive from overwriting UEFI records?
When I tried booting a 2.5" HDD with multiple OSes bootstrapped onto it through a SATA to USB adapter, the boot record the existing Arch Linux installation on my system (MSI Modern 14 C7M) was wiped.
External HDD:

100Mi shared EFI partition between Arch Linux and Windows boot manager
250Gi Windows 11 instance 1
500Gi Windows 11 instance 2
181Gi Arch Linux instance

Internal SSD:

512Mi EFI system partition
472Gi Arch Linux instance

It seems that instead of recognising the external HDD as a USB drive like through other SATA adapters, this one reports it to the system that it is a hard drive.
After booting into windows and rebooting, it also seemed that the boot record for Arch Linux instance on the external HDD was wiped, and the system would only boot to Windows boot manager.
How do I stop Windows from overwriting my internal SSD's boot records?

What you think happened just didn't because it can't.

Does this happen after booting a specific OS? i.e. does it happen specifically after booting Windows? or merely after connecting the disk and going into EFI?

Some PC's, e.g., some Dell machines, have a BIOS/UEFI to disable the internal drive. Yes, it is not optimal that one need change those settings each time booting from external media, but it is one workaround.

It does appear that it only happens after booting into windows after some experimentation. I will edit my question.
The MSI bios doesn't have an option to edit efi boot records, nor a built-in efi shell that can be booted to from it

Is Startup Repair running, or is bootrec being run, at any point the external drive is plugged in? When dual-booting BSD/Linux with Windows, bootrec will overwrite GRUB (which is one utility Startup Repair uses to repair the BCD Store), necessitating the use of a Linux utility to repair the BCD Store (essentially the only time a Linux utility is required to fix a Windows boot issue).

It's kind of tricky since you need both of:

Make the grub EFI executable on the ESP (of the external drive) "portable", as in "auto-discoverable"
Avoid using the "Windows Boot Manager" entry (which with at least some UEFI firmware there would/could be only one such entry, resulting in it being overwritten by another instance/set of WBM, even when it's on the/a ESP of another disk) and allow the UEFI firmware to auto-discover the EFI executable copy of Windows Boot Manager at EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi

Essentially the only way to achieve #2 is to "constantly" delete EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi, since there would be a copy of it at EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi
(Constantly here essentially means every time after a Cumulative Update is applied, so it's like monthly.) Also, you probably need to do this for both the internal and external drive.
The thing is, to achieve #1, what you need would be to have the grub EFI executable resides at EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi (Either you move the file at EFI/arch/grubx64.efi, or run grub-install with --removable.)
And the only solution to achieve both is probably to have separate ESP for grub and Windows Boot Manager respectively. (And if your UEFI firmware looks at only the first ESP / FAT-formatted partition of each disk for EFI executables at EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi, use grub to chainload the one on the Windows Boot Manager ESP.)
P.S. If you also have grub in the internal drive (in a dedicated ESP) and use it to chainload WBM, you might or might not need to keep deleting EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi copies, depending if the WBM entry would get moved to the top of the boot priority whenever updated (if that's the case, the deletion will keep it "invalid").
